# Performance problem while making a rich text editor in xamarin

Tags: performance, xamarin, richtextbox

We want to make a rich (but not too rich) text editor with xamarin such that it is possible to:

1. Highlight some words
2. Position the cursor anywhere with the mouse or touch
3. Show the position of the cursor

Our attempt is using a *Label* to display text, and when the user click on the label in reality a hidden *Entry* is focused. To reposition the cursor we split the *FormattedString* in more *Span*, one for each character, so we know which is tapped or clicked.

The problem now is performance, as the content grows the time of updating the view grows a lot. For example just for adding one character can take 3000 ms if the content length is around 30 character. By the way it takes just 10 ms if the content length is little like 1-5 characters. The time to update the label is not linear on the length of text.

Here I put the code where the performance problem occur, and I want ask you if there is a problem in my code or maybe I can't do this in xamarin in this way.

```
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        
        string newText = e.NewTextValue;
        string oldText = (e.OldTextValue ?? string.Empty);

        List<string> newParts = newText.Split('#').ToList();
        List<string> oldParts = oldText.Split('#').ToList();

        // ...

        foreach (string part in newParts)
        {
            string placeholderCode = $"#{part}#";
            string textToShow = isPlaceholder ? placeholders[placeholderCode] : part;

            if (isPlaceholder)
            {
                editorPosition += placeholderCode.Length;
            }

            Span tmpSpan = new Span();

            foreach (char character in textToShow)
            {
                Span item = viewer.FormattedText.Spans.ElementAtOrDefault(currentSpan++);
                
                if (item == null)
                {
                    item = new Span();

                    TapGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();

                    gestureRecognizer.Tapped += delegate { 
                        editor.CursorPosition = spanToEditorPosition[item];
                        FocusEditor();
                    };

                    item.GestureRecognizers.Add(gestureRecognizer);

                    viewer.FormattedText.Spans.Add(item);
                }

                if (isPlaceholder)
                {
                    tmpSpan.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
                }
                else
                {
                    tmpSpan.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None;
                    editorPosition++;
                }

                tmpSpan.Text = character.ToString();

                if (tmpSpan.Text != item.Text || tmpSpan.FontAttributes != item.FontAttributes)
                {
                    item.Text = tmpSpan.Text;
                    item.FontAttributes = tmpSpan.FontAttributes;
                }

                spanToEditorPosition.Add(item, editorPosition);
            }

            isPlaceholder = !isPlaceholder;
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
```

Comment: first, have you profiled your code to determine where the performance issue is?  Second, I suspect something like this should really be implemented at the platform level and exposed with a custom renderer, not directly in forms.

Comment: Thank you @jason for the comment. I measured the execution time using the StopWatch class, I don't know how to use and how works a profiler. 
Do you mean should I create a custom Label and a custom Label-Renderer?

Comment: you have profiled the overall loop, but the next step would be to profile the inner loops and individual statements to determine which one(s) are the worst offenders